# Converting pointer to member function to std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, std-function

I have a slightly convoluted use case of passing a member function pointer to an outside function which is then called again by a member function (Don't ask!). I'm learning about `std::function` and `std::mem_fn` but I can't seem to be able to convert my old school function pointer

`void (T::*func)(int)` to a `std::function<void (T::*)(int) func>`

in the code below, I'd like to be able to pass a std::function to `memFuncTaker` in the call from `anotherMember`

```
#include "class2.hpp" 
#include <iostream> 

class outer{ 
public: 
  void aMember(int a){ 
    std::cout << a <<std::endl; 
  } 
  void anotherMember(double){ 
    memFuncTaker(this, &outer::aMember); 
  } 

}; 


template<class T> 
void memFuncTaker(T* obj , void (T::*func)(int) ){ 
  (obj->*func)(7); 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any attempts to use `std::function` in your code.

Comment: Your question title says "Converting pointer to member function to std::function", but the question sounds like "Converting std::function to pointer to member function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind `std::function` to a non-static member function pointer, it "reveals" the hidden `this` parameter, making it the first explicit parameter of the resultant functor. So in your case for `outer::aMember` you'd use `std::function<void(outer *, int)>` and end up with a two-parameter functor

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream> 

template<class T> 
void memFuncTaker(T *obj , std::function<void(T *, int)> func){ 
  func(obj, 7);
} 

class outer{ 
public: 
  void aMember(int a){ 
    std::cout << a <<std::endl; 
  } 
  void anotherMember(double){ 
    memFuncTaker(this, std::function<void(outer *, int)>{&outer::aMember}); 
  } 
}; 

int main() {
  outer o;
  o.anotherMember(0);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e9d2486c4c45138

Of course, if you prefer, you can bind the first argument of that functor (by using `std::bind` or lambda) and thus "hide" it again

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std::placeholders;

void memFuncTaker(std::function<void(int)> func){ 
  func(7);
} 

class outer{ 
public: 
  void aMember(int a){ 
    std::cout << a <<std::endl; 
  } 
  void anotherMember(double){ 
    memFuncTaker(std::function<void(int)>(std::bind(&outer::aMember, this, _1))); 
  } 
}; 

int main() {
  outer o;
  o.anotherMember(0);
}
```

Note that in this version `memFuncTaker` no longer has to be a template (which happens to be one of the primary purposes of `std::function` - employ type erasure techniques to "de-templatize" the code).

Comment: How come the return type of  `std::bind(&outer::aMember, this, _1)` is `std::function<void(int)>`. I know `aMember` is a member function but how come `this` doesn't show up the function signature bound to  `std::function`. I expected `std::bind(&outer::aMember, this, _1)` to return `std::function<void(outer*, int)>`

Comment: @creationist: Why? The whole purpose of that `std::bind` is to eliminate (bind) the first (`outer *`) parameter. *Before* `std::bind` the functor had two parameters - `outer *` and `int`, - but *after* `std::bind` only one was left: `int`.

Comment: For another example, if you do `std::mem_fn(&outer::aMember)` you will get a two-parameter functior (just like you described). But if after that you do `std::bind(std::mem_fn(&outer::aMember), this, _1)` only one parameter will be left. What you see in my answer above is the same thing, since `std::mem_fn` is optional in this context and can be omitted. `std::bind` is smart enough to realize what is meant without explicit application of `std::mem_fn`.